# Каждый четный раз форма Ajax не отправляется

Tags: javascript, ajax, octobercms

Есть страничка с несколькими формами и одинаковыми полями, но в js отлавливается событие submit конкретной формы и отправляется на сервер. И первый раз все работает хорошо, а вот если второй раз отправить хоть ту же форму с новыми значениями хоть соседнюю - происходит перезагрузка страницы а в адресной строке появлется get-запрос.Если еще раз отправить - то все будет работать правильно.

Сами формочки:

```html
<form class="kvm-form">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="kvmid">
    <label class="sr-only" for="time-1">Время</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm time">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time-1" name="timefor" value="02:00">
    </div>
    <div class="ticket">
      <label class="sr-only" for="ticket-1">Тикет</label>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">#</span>
        </div>
        <input type="num" class="form-control" id="ticket-1" name="ticket">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rack">
      <label class="sr-only" for="rack-1">Стойка</label>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm rack">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-server"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rack-1" name="rack">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="width: 100px;">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</form>

<form class="kvm-form">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="kvmid">
    <label class="sr-only" for="time-2">Время</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm time">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time-2" name="timefor" value="02:00">
    </div>
    <div class="ticket">
      <label class="sr-only" for="ticket-2">Тикет</label>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">#</span>
        </div>
        <input type="num" class="form-control" id="ticket-2" name="ticket">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rack">
      <label class="sr-only" for="rack-2">Стойка</label>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm rack">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-server"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rack-2" name="rack">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="width: 100px;">Добавить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ajax (Если что, в коде есть специфика JSON-Api October CMS):

```js
$('form.kvm-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $form = $(this);
  $form.request('onKvmUpdate', {
    update: {
      'kvms::kvms-table': '#kvm-table'
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      //this.success(data);
      //viewKvmModal(data);
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
});
```

Обработчик просто записывает в БД и отправляет данные для перерендеринга части страниицы.

Я даже специально использовал конструкцию $form = $(this); - но не помогло. Работает ровно через раз. Что может вызвать такое поведение?

Comment: Какая именно часть меняется?

Comment: Меняется вся таблица в которой находятся формы

Comment: @InDevX ААА, я правильно начинаю понимать, что саму форму луше не менять, ведь для дерева - это совершенно другой объект? Или это бред?)

Comment: Верно, для dom это уже другой объект

Comment: `$('form.kvm-form').on('submit', function(event) {` замените на `$(document).on('submit', 'form.kvm-form', function(event) {`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Даже не знал о существовании такой конструкции

Comment: Это [делегирование событий](https://habr.com/ru/post/512782/) называется. Условно, мы считываем документ, находим там эл-т и вешаем на него событие, а при обычном подходе сразу  находим эл-т и вешаем событие